# Excel: How to convert a decimal number into a 3 Byte binary

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Consider the decimal number `10093264`. I want to convert this number into a 3 Byte binary number and show the value of each byte as decimal. I.e. I want to rewrite the aforementioned number as:

`154   2   208`

So, what would be a possible way to achieve this?

I was thinking `DEC2BIN` to give me the binary number. But here is the problem: This function allows only inputs of up to 8 bits! My math is not the best, so maybe s.o. can help me out: What do I need to divide by what? 
I realized, for example, that `QUOTIENT(10093264;2^16)` gives `154`, which is my LSB. But I cannot apply the same method to give me the other bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BITAND` (Bitwise And), and Integer division or `BITRSHIFT` (Bitwise Right Shift)

So, the smallest byte (`208`) will just be `=BITAND(10093264,255)` - this will give you the last 8 bits:

```
  100110100000001011010000 : 10093264
& 000000000000000011111111 : 255
= 000000000000000011010000 : 208
```

For the next smallest byte (`2`), you can start by either Integer Division (`INT(10093264/256)`) or `BITRSHIFT` (`BITRSHIFT(10093264, 8)`), then use `BITAND` on that again:

```
  100110100000001011010000 : 10093264
→ 000000001001101000000010 : 39426
& 000000000000000011111111 : 255
= 000000000000000000000010 : 2
```

Then, do the same again for the next byte:  either `BITRSHIFT` by 16 (2 bytes) or divide by 65536 (i.e. `POWER(256,2)`)

```
  100110100000001011010000 : 10093264
→ 000000000000000010011010 : 208
& 000000000000000011111111 : 255
= 000000000000000010011010 : 208
```

If you want to do it all in 1 cell (and have Office 365, for the `TEXTJOIN` function) then you can use this Array Formula.  It used `LOG` to work out how many bytes there are, and outputs with spaces:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",FALSE,BITAND(BITRSHIFT(A1,8*(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,CEILING.MATH(LOG($A1,256))))-1)),255))
```

(As an Array Formula, you will need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when you put it in)

Answer (score 1):

function

```
=ROUNDDOWN(10093264/2^16,0) & " " & ROUNDDOWN(MOD(10093264,2^16)/2^8,0) & " " & ROUNDDOWN(MOD(MOD(10093264,2^16),2^8),0)
```